# React Rich Text Editor that actually works in mobile?

Tags: reactjs, rich-text-editor, quill, draftjs, slatejs

I need to implement a rich text editor into a React app. The general choices are Draft, Slate, etc..
I tried probably all of the "top 15" editors.
most fail miserably on Android. Draft is just unusable. Many have very strange behavior when selecting text. 
Quill was alright but pasting a large piece of html literally takes like 10 seconds for some reason instead of <1 second.
I don't need anything like tables or images or videos. just text with formatting.

Is there anything out there that does basic function like bold/italics/alignment and allows for custom functions but is rock solid on mobile and also has a proper react interface?

I previously used Trumbowyg on a jQuery based site and it was nice and simple. I had to tweak it a bit to take care of pasting things like word docs but at least the interface didn't take a month to learn.

Ideally my RTE would have these features:
1 - simple interface
2 - rock solid (as much as possible given limitations) on ios/android
3 - support custom toolbar buttons with custom functions
4 - cleans up crazy pasted html (like MS Word) or at least exposes some interface that lets me clean it up
5 - has a proper react interface

Comment: So I came across Trix .. seems to work fairly well but the documentation is AWFUL. Plus full JS source code is not available.. only coffeescript (which I am not comfortable with). At this point a paid plugin is looking more attractive

Answer (score -1):

we are using Judit editor, but it is not perfect at all.
would love to get a recommendation for a replacement..